# Inks cargo contract error

Tags: ink

[image]

What is the reason it cannot load the wasm blob by cargo contract?
This problem persist even for newly ink project.

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/1058#issuecomment-1501225760

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the same error when building my chain binary, it looks like it is related to the toolchain `1.68` and not your code.

When I changed toolchain to `nightly-2023-01-01-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` it disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to rust stable channel by default and then run `cargo contract build --release`